# Twitter API limitations for applications

Tags: rest, api, twitter, content-management-system, rate-limiting

I would like to make a content management system that would post tweets on behalf of another user.

As far as I understand the rate limit for the twitter API at the moment is 15 requests per 15 minutes per user/application as described on their website. So in my case posting a tweet on behalf of another user would count as one request.

If this is the situation, creating a content management system would be unrealistic as an increase in the amount of users will cause rate limiting errors.

Is there any way around this or is this the limit of posting to twitter on behalf of another user?

I am new to this situation so I do apologize if I am incorrect. Thanks in advance.